# What does struct_type[1] mean?

Tags: c, struct, sizeof

I found some code that gets the size of struct like this:

```
sizeof(struct struct_type[1]);
```

I tested and it does return the size of `struct_type`.

And

```
sizeof(struct struct_type[2]);
```

returns twice the struct size.

**Edit:**

`struct_type` is a struct, not an array:

```
struct struct_type {
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

What does `struct_type[1]` actually mean?

Comment: `struct_type` is probably an array of structs, `sizeof(struct struct_type[1]);` gets the size of the first element in the array of structs.

Comment: @iwin no, it's not an arrray, kindly see my update

Comment: How do you declare an array of `struct_type`? Now think how you get the size of that array by type. This is typically not good practice, as one better takes the `sizeof` an object, i.e. either a variable or by dereferencing a pointer to the type. That way your code will not break if you change the type of the object. Another issue is the usage of an integer constant in the code (aka "magic number"). Bad practice, use a `#define` (aka macro).

Comment: After ``int a[5];``, we get ``sizeof(int)==4, sizeof(int[5])==20, sizeof(a)==20, sizeof(a[5])==4``.  Logical? `:-)`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Remember `sizeof` syntax:

```
sizeof ( typename );
```

Here typename is `struct struct_type[N]` or in more readable form `struct struct_type [N]` which is an array of N objects of type struct struct_type. As you know array size is the size of one element multiplied by the total number of elements.

Answer (score 13):

Just like:

```
sizeof(int[1]); // will return the size of 1 int
```

and

```
sizeof(int[2]); // will return the size of 2 ints
```

So does:

```
sizeof(struct struct_type[1]); // return size of 1 `struct struct_type'
```

and

```
sizeof(struct struct_type[2]); // return size of 2 `struct struct_type'
```

Here `struct struct_type[1]`, and `struct struct_type[2]` simply represent `arrays` of elements of type `struct struct_type`, and `sizeof` of is just  returning the size of those represented arrays.

Comment: No, it will not. It will not even compile. You cannot have a declaration in `sizeof`

Comment: Not only that, but both will return the size of int*.

Comment: @Doddy; No. Not at all.

Comment: @Doddy Did you get that result in your system? Which OS, and compiler?

Comment: I havent tried it, but surely the type of ´sizeof(int[x])´ is always the size of int* for any x because you are declaring an integer array.

Comment: @Doddy Array decays to pointer when it is passed as argument to a function. This does _not_ happen with `sizeof` operator. `sizeof` is an operator, not a function. If still in doubt, please verify by trying in your system.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit OK, I get that. I can't say I'm not surprised though, because I think this is bad practice. Giving examples like these could lead to people using sizeof() on pointers from array declarations thinking that it will return the length of the memory.

Comment: @Doddy: What do you mean by "pointers from array declarations"? Array declarations do not give you pointers; they give you arrays.

Comment: @Doddy That's okay; I've been insane for centuries. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I could take time to explain, but it probably wouldn't help how stupid I feel; basically I've never used sizeof() on an *array*; I've always used it with the underlying type times the count, i.e. `sizeof(int) * x`. Meh, years of C still brings up surprises!

Comment: @Doddy: FWIW, I tend to agree that giving _any_ examples with `sizeof` in is bad practice and leads to people doing all sorts of weird, broken crap.

Answer (score 7):

For the declaration

```
int arr[10];
```

size of array can be calculated by either using `arr` as an operand or `int [10]`. Since `sizeof` operator yields the size based on the type of operand, both `sizeof(arr)` and `sizeof (int [10])` will return the size of array `arr` (ultimately `arr` is of type `int [10]`).

C11-§6.5.3.3/2:

> The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an
>   expression or the parenthesized name of a type. **The size is determined from the type of the operand**. The result is an integer. If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an integer constant.

Similarly, for an array of `struct struct_type`

```
struct struct_type a[1];
```

size can be calculated either by `sizeof (a)` or `sizeof(struct struct_type[1])`.